# How to check if all elements of an array are of a certain value?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want a method to return `true` when all the elements of an array are equal and are `"yes"`. I have one array `["yes", "yes", "yes"]`. All its elements are the same `"yes"`. I want it to return `true`. For `["no", "no", "no"]`, although all the elements are `"no"`, the value is not equal to `"yes"`. How can I do that?

I am using this method to check this:

```
def self.all_equal?(array) array.max == array.min end
```

but it returns `true` for `["no", "no", "no"]`.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. Your code is not even syntactically valid.

Answer (score 5):

This should solve your problem:

```
def self.all_equal?(array) 
  array.uniq == ['yes'] 
end
```

Comment: This incorrectly returns `false` for an empty array. But the question was not necessarily clear on that.

Answer (score 4):

```
def self.all_equal_to_yes? array
   array.all? { |x| x == "yes" }
end
```

Note that this will return `true` for the empty array. If you want it to return `false` in that case, use FixerRB's answer. I also used the name `all_equal_to_yes?` since that makes what the method is doing much more explicit than just `all_equal?`. You could also define a more general method:

```
def self.all_equal_to?(array, value)
    array.all? { |x| x == value
end
```

And then be able to call it like so:

```
$ Foo.all_equal_to? ["no", "no", "no"], "yes"
#=> false
$ Foo.all_equal_to? ["no", "no", "no"], "no"
#=> true
```

(Replace `Foo` with whatever class you're defining this method on)

Comment: You should delete both your answer to the question that was not asked and  your remark about having initially misread the question. That's all excess baggage.

Comment: I can agree with that. I'll leave the naming note though, I wouldn't consider that excess baggage, since the poor naming is what led me to misunderstand the question (well, that and the poor original title before sawa fixed it).

Answer (score 2):

I know this was a couple of years ago, but I stumbled upon this question and thought I'd share something I recently learned:

```
value = "yes"
array.all?(value)  #=> returns true
```

so then you'd be changing the value input as you like.

Answer (score 1):

```
["yes", "yes", "yes"].grep_v("yes").empty? # => true
["no", "yes", "yes"] .grep_v("yes").empty? # => false
["no", "no", "no"]   .grep_v("yes").empty? # => false
```

Answer (score 0):

The current method just checks if all the elements of an array are equal. If you want to also check that they are all equal to `"yes"`, you'll need to add an explicit check for this. Since they are all equal, it's sufficient to check that one of them is indeed `"yes"`:

```
def self.all_equal?(array) array.max == array.min && array[0] == "yes" end
```